# Formulating Canonical Momentum in terms of Contour Integrals?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum

### Background

In the special case of a single particle with wavefunction $\psi(r)$. The translation operator for a small amount is written by:

$$\hat T( a )\psi(r) =  \psi( r - a ) = \psi( r) - a \frac{\partial}{\partial r} 
 \psi( r) + O(a^2)$$

**Usual Formulation (of momentum):**

Now, the usual formulation to define momentum along an axis is given by:

$$(\hat T( a ) - \hat T(0)) \psi(r) = - a \frac{\partial}{\partial r} 
 \psi( r) + O(a^2)$$

Dividing by $a$ and taking the limit of $a \to 0$:

$$\lim_{a \to 0}\frac{(\hat T( a ) - \hat T(0))}{a} \psi(r) =  - \frac{\partial}{\partial r} 
 \psi( r) $$

Multiplying $i \hbar$ both sides:

$$i \hbar \lim_{a \to 0}\frac{(\hat T( a ) - I)}{a} \psi(r) =-  i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial r} 
 \psi( r) = \hat p \psi (r)$$

**Another Formulation (of momentum):**

$$\hat T( a )\psi(r) =  \psi( r - a ) = \psi( r) - a \frac{\partial}{\partial r} 
 \psi( r) + O(a^2)$$

Dividing by $a^2$:

$$\frac{1}{a^2}\hat T( a )\psi(r) = \frac{1}{a^2} \psi( r) - \frac{1}{a} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} 
 \psi( r) + O(1) $$

Taking the contour integral:

$$\oint \frac{da}{a^2}\hat T( a )\psi(r) = - 2 \pi i \frac{\partial}{\partial r} 
 \psi( r)  $$

Upon further manipulating:

$$\frac{\hbar}{ 2 \pi}\oint \frac{da}{a^2}\hat T( a )\psi(r) = -   i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial r} 
 \psi( r)  = \hat p \psi$$

### Question

Is there a formulation of canonical momentum in terms of contour integrals?

Comment: Analyticity would typically be an extra assumption.

Comment: @Qmechanic is there any physical system where this becomes a bad thing?

Comment: Also related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/158432/